# Ubuntu 18.04 Fresh install, internet speeds are abysmal in comparison to other devices

Tags: networking, intel

I was using manjaro before but had some issue with it that left me to come back to Ubuntu. After installing (minimal and install device drivers) I went to start downloading tools to find I was getting around 70kb/s on my snap download. I checked on Firefox and it also takes a ton of time to load sites and do basic browsing. I attempted a speedtest.net and I couldn't complete the test because of a latency error I've never seen before. I have a Lenovo Legion Y720. My network controller is Intel Corp Wireless 8265 / 8275. I am also running linux5.3 kernel version. If there is anything else that's needed please let me know. Thanks for your time and help!

```
  lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TeamTom"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.66 GHz  Access Point: A6:9A:93:FD:92:A5   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2075  Invalid misc:26   Missed beacon:0

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

RX and TX errors are both 0 on ifconfig

Comment: Forgot to add things that Ive tried. I looked at some other places and I tried disabling 802.11n protocol but that did nothing. I opened my laptop up to try and see if the network card was seated incorrectly but it's fine. I also tried changing DNS but that did nothing also.

Comment: I would first check `ifconfig` for RX/TX errors. Also please add `iwconfig` output to the question.

Comment: added iwconfig and RX/TX error were both at zero

Comment: Did you try Ubuntu kernels?

Comment: Like I should try using a different kernel?

Comment: That is slow. Check `iw reg get` just to make sure your region is correct. Then I would do `journalctl -a | grep wlp | more` and see if there are any issues.

Comment: iw reg get did show a country code of 00 on global but looked up the solution and its set to CA now

Comment: For WiFi connections, your MTU should be 1492, rather than 1500. `ifconfig w1p2s0` to check. Or install `tracepath` and let it show you your `pmtu` (Path MTU). Avoid Packet Fragmentation!